# How to print the cause for a thrown Error in Chrome console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-dev-editor

Since July 2021 they have added a new error cause property in Javascript, so we are able to do:

```
throw new Error('New error message', { cause: err });
```

In Firefox this err object is shown after the original error. On Chrome only the original error is shown, and I can't store the thrown error into variable to inspect it. How do I see the error cause then? (Without modifying the source code / get into the debugger)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don’t think there's a way unless you catch the error before it's being thrown with the "Pause debugger on uncaught errors".

We'll have to wait until Chrome natively includes the `cause`’s stack trace in when displaying the error, just like Firefox and Node do. This is being tracked here:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1211260